# upper() case of number key

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to implement an input box in PyGame. I've gotten to a point where I can input text in lower and upper case letters (SHIFT changes to upper case, as usual). I do this by checking whether L_SHIFT/R_SHIFT is pressed and if it is, I use something like `char = char.upper()` to turn the char that corresponds to the pressed key into the corresponding upper char. This works fine with letters (`a-z -> A-Z`). However it does not work with numbers and other special symbols like `1 -> !`, `2 -> "`,  `. -> :` or `, -> ;` (German keyboard layout).

Is there a better way in Python to turn chars into their corresponding SHIFT+key chars?

Comment: You might be able to capture the _character_ of SHIFT+key combination by checking the `unicode` attribute of the `pygame.KEYDOWN` event. I noted the pygame.key documentation says: unicode represents a single character string that is the fully translated character entered. This takes into account the shift and composition keys.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528951/pygame-keyboard-layouts-mixed-up

Answer (score 1):

There is no inherent mapping from numbers to the punctuation marks associated with them on the keyboard, so you'll have to specify them yourself.  I would use a map, like this:

```
number_map = {
  '1':'!',
  '2':'@',
  '3':'#',
  #etc
  #etc
}

print(number_map['1']) # will print !
```

This is nice because you can also use it for any other non-alphabetic keys.

Comment: Bummer... I knew it was going to be something like this. I was hoping for a library or something that did this based on the system language/keymap...

Comment: I don't have experience with PyGame, so I'm not positive it doesn't have anything for this. I just looked at some docs and didn't see anything though.  You may want to look a little more though!

Comment: To make mapping them a bit easier `{ n : p for n, p in zip('1234567890', '!@#$%^&*()') }`