# Pygame adds ENG US keyboard layout when calling pygame.init

Tags: pygame

Whenever I call `pygame.init()`, the default English keyboard is added to my layout switcher. How can I prevent that? I have tried the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/483086/how-do-i-remove-automatically-added-keyboard-layouts/484595#484595), but it doesn't help.

EDIT 2016/12/07: After further testing, I have determined that, of the six modules that pygame initializes in its init method, `pygame.display.init` is definitely at least partially to blame. `import pygame.display as dsp; dsp.init()` results in the addition of the layout. [pygame_sdl2](https://github.com/renpy/pygame_sdl2), however, does not exhibit this behavior, although I don't know whether that is simply because whatever part of the `pygame.display` module causes this hasn't been implemented yet or because of a meaningful difference in implementation.

Comment: Here, I think I fount a workaround/temporary solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528951/pygame-keyboard-layouts-mixed-up

Comment: @C._ I'm asking about the keyboard being added to the language switcher, not checking for letters. It doesn't change the software layout, but it adds an unwanted option that I have specifically removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here, about changing the [keyboard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420925/change-keyboard-layout-with-python)

PS: Sorry I can't reply directly to your comment. Don't have the ability to do that yet.

Comment: It's not a problem of *switching* layouts, it's a problem of *adding* an unwanted layout.

Comment: @cuddlebugCuller [try this](http://superuser.com/questions/395818/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-via-command-line-cmd-exe-on-windows-xp-7)

Comment: @cuddlebugCuller Sorry, accidentally hit enter. Go to that url, which shows how to delete keyboard layouts from cmd. Then, use this to run the code from python :  `import os `                                                                `command = [the code line that should be run from cmd]`                             `os.system(command)`. It's a little complex, but I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this seems like something that MS seems to have not exposed. I tried the `control intl.cpl` thing and I tried just resetting the WinUserLanguageList directly with Powershell, but both seem to require a restart if they work at all.